# segment error in c when i set ls = temp->next，ls、temp are both pointer equal to the same link head pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the function partition when I define two pointers(ls、temp) equal to the same link head，and then get segment error when set ls = temp->next。what's the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 */
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

typedef struct ListNode * list;

struct ListNode* partition(struct ListNode* head, int x){
    list ls,temp = head;
    ls->next = temp;
    return head;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    struct ListNode * head, * temp;
    head = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    temp = head;
    for (i=8; i>0; i--) {
        struct ListNode *n = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        n->val = i;
        n->next = NULL;
        temp->next = n;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    head = partition(head->next, 4);
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", temp->val);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: ls doesn’t have storage, it is just a pointer.... malloc/calloc it.

Comment: `list ls, temp = head;` only initializes `temp`, it doesn't initialize `ls`

Comment: It's the same as `list ls; list temp = head;`

Comment: The problem is the line `list ls,temp = head;` which is equal to `list ls; list temp = head;`. 
`ls` is not initialized to any value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers。The reason is that temp does not initialized and I don't malloc/calloc memory for it。Change to `list temp = head;     list ls = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));     ls->next = temp;` works。